# Most General Theory of Stochastic Integration

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I've learnt continuous stochastic integration using the classical books:
- Revuz & Yor,
- Karatzas & Shreve and
- Oksendal.

Now I want to learn general stochastic integration, i.e. possibly discontinuous semimartingales.

Can anyone recommend some literature, which covers this topics and also provides some exercises?

Answer (score 1):

The monograph *Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations* by Philip E. Protter covers stochastic integration with respect to semimartingales and provides exercises at the end of each chapter. This is the standard reference, I would say (at least for graduate students).

The first part of *Limit Processes for Stochastic Processes* by Jean Jacod and Albert Shiryaev also discusses stochastic integration with respect to semimartingales. Although this is not an easy read, you should manage if you are familiar with stochastic processes and integration (with respect to continuous martingales) and if you like rigorous books. However, the book doesn't contain any exercises.

Comment: Does Protter provide the most general framework of stochastic integration w.r.t. semimartingales?

Comment: @Dan How do you define "most general"? Semimartingales are the most general stochastic integrators. (And if you are interested in "most most general" things, then you can't expect that such a book contains exercises.)

Comment: I mean, does Protter restrict to some special classes of semimartingales? 
Thank you for your helpful comments.

Comment: @Dan As far as I remember, the presentation is not restricted to special classes. (However, there is *some* technical condition to ensure that the integral extends from simple integrands to a larger class of integrands.) Why not have a look at it? You might even find it (or at least a preview) in the web, e.g. google.books

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations. 
I have one more question:
What is the difference between Protter and Jacod Shiryaev?

Comment: @Dan As I already mentioned, Protter's book aims at graduate students; this means that (compared with Jacod/Shiryaev) there are more detailed explanations/examples. Stochastic integration is one of *the* topics in the book. This is not true for Jacod/Shiryaev's book, their main topics are "deeper" results (and stochastic integration is one of the required tools to prove them).

Comment: @ Dan : It's not a book rather a blog untitled "almost Sure" where George Lowther gives a good and very original and self contained account on the most general stochastic integration theory. For more classical reference a good one very general (but with many typos and a style which is particular) is "Semimartingale Theory and Stochastic Calculus" by He, Wang, Yan. Otherwise but a little outdated is the great Strasbourg School account of Dellacherie Meyer "Probabilities and Potential". Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Protters book uses a more modern approach based on functional analysis - whereas Jacod uses the "classical approach". 
Jacods exposition is very short (but nevertheless rigorous) - the whole theory is developed in less than 60 pages. (Personally i found Jacods book better)

I want to point out a third option. In fact this is perhaps the most rigorous and self contained treatment you can get (as literally every basic property of martingales is proven as well) - however it requires a lot of time and dedication. Its the book "Probabilities and Potential  B: Theory of Martingales" from Dellacherie & Meyer.